# How can I capture all event in a form

Tags: c#

For every event I have to write an event handler:

```
this.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(Home_MouseMove);
this.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(Home_KeyPress);
```

What if I one to capture every button handler, then I would have to write a event handler for each buttons.

Any good method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach an event for every control of type `Button` on the `Form_Load` event. Even better, in the constructor itself after the call to `InitializeComponent`.

Why 'after'? Because if you do before, there will be no control on the form to attach to.

```
foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
{
   if(c is Button)
   {
        // Just an example, mold it to fit your app.
        ((Button) c).Click += new MouseClickHandler();
   }
}
```

Note that if you have a `Panel` control with Buttons in it, this will not attach the event to it, as that button is not part of the Form ("this") collection of `.Controls`; but rather `this.Panel1.Controls`. See?

If this is the case for you, you can use recursion to iterate though each collection.